# How to make Nginx to not serve direct requests?

Tags: nginx, request, varnish

I use Nginx (port `:8080`) with Varnish (port `:80`) for a while now and I want to serve an error page if I get a direct request to mydomain.com:8080.

Can you tell me how could I do that the easiest way?

Comment: Make nginx listen to localhost only

Comment: @AlexeyTen But if I do that, I cannot serve error pages for the users, I think. (Edit: but I can redirect them to Port `:80` :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I made every config file to `listen` to `127.0.0.1:8080` and then made a new file which does not have specified `server_name`. This file returns us to the error page (404 for example).

If you are looking for the same answer but you want to redirect your domain to port `:80` then use a config like this (for the domain itself):

```
server {
    listen      8080;
    server_name .domain.com;

    # redirect foo.domain.com:8080/bar to foo.domain.com/bar
    if ($host ~* "^([^.]+(\.[^.]+)*)\.domain.com$") {
        set $s $1;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$s.domain.com$1 permanent;
        break;
    }

    # redirect domain.com:8080/bar to domain.com/bar
    if ($host ~* "^domain.com$") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://domain.com$1 permanent;
        break;
    }

    # return error (your users have no way to get here!)
    return 500;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to write, but I cannot answer my own questions for 8 hours if I have a rep. value under 10. Thanks to post this for me Józse! :)